# How can I learn how to create a delegation engine?

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, security

One of the last places I worked at had a delegation engine in SharePoint, a SharePoint List that specified the SharePoint groups that would be sought for approval for a workflow based on that workflows code. Anybody in that SharePoint Group could approve  the task and then the workflow would proceed to the next specified group in the delegation engine.

I'm now working elsewhere, and I want to build a similar system - but I've no idea what this kind of a delegations system is called or how to research it. How can something like this be done? I have access to SharePoint 2013 and Nintex Workflows Enterprise, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can use Nintex out of the box delegation task
check the following links about using nintex delegation

http://www.letssharepoint.com/2009/10/nintex-best-practice-task-delegation.html

http://connect.nintex.com/files/folders/workflow_add-ons_nw2010/entry14989.aspx

2- Build your own solution by having list to hold the delegation information such as start date, end date, delegate from, delegate to. build a web part to manage delegations. Then you have to listen to created tasks and update the assigned to field value using event receiver on tasks list for example.

There are an existing open source delegation framework [here](http://megrentaskdelegation.codeplex.com/)

also the following article explain how to build your own system http://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/build-tasks-delegation-in-sharepoint-2010/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Nintex workflows have a built in delegation feature that can be enabled on their Approval actions that allow the user to specify a delegate. There is also an option to set up a delegate in the Nintex options in their Nintex Workflow 2010 Task Delegation settings under their personalization settings.